# My NSMutableDictionary removes object When i delete NSMutableArray in IOS?

Tags: ios, contacts

```
contactSectionDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
contactsForSection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
contactsIndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H",@"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z",@"#"];

for(int i=0;i<contactsIndexTitles.count;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<names.count;j++)
    {
        NSArray * splitArray = [[names objectAtIndex:j] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        if ([[splitArray objectAtIndex:0] hasPrefix:[contactsIndexTitles objectAtIndex:i]]) {
            //[contactSectionDict setValue:[names objectAtIndex:j] forKey:[contactsIndexTitles objectAtIndex:i]];
            [contactsForSection addObject:[names objectAtIndex:j]];
        }
    }
    [contactSectionDict setValue:contactsForSection forKey:[contactsIndexTitles objectAtIndex:i]];
    [contactsForSection removeAllObjects];
}
```

In the first iteration it stores 36 objects in contactsForSection and store it in contactsectionDict for Key"A" then i want to store contacts for index B and for that purpose i remove objects from contactsForSection , but it also remove value for the key"A" in dictionary also.
when the dictionary will set against all indexes then i ll give it to table view for display them like Apple Contact Application.
Kindly suggest me the better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `contactsForSection` Array for each letter:

```
contactSectionDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
contactsIndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H",@"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z",@"#"];

for(int i=0;i<contactsIndexTitles.count;i++)
{
    contactsForSection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int j=0;j<names.count;j++)
    {
        NSArray * splitArray = [[names objectAtIndex:j] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        if ([[splitArray objectAtIndex:0] hasPrefix:[contactsIndexTitles objectAtIndex:i]]) {
            //[contactSectionDict setValue:[names objectAtIndex:j] forKey:[contactsIndexTitles objectAtIndex:i]];
            [contactsForSection addObject:[names objectAtIndex:j]];
        }
    }
    [contactSectionDict setValue:contactsForSection forKey:[contactsIndexTitles objectAtIndex:i]];
    [contactsForSection removeAllObjects];
}
```